# Use Random Number to generate 3 other options

Tags: jquery, random

I have one random variable which selects any random numbers between 1-10. I have done this using `var rand1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9)+1);`

I want to create a question in which user will have to guess the random number which is generated. I want to give user 4 options which includes `rand1`.

What will be the best way to generate the other 3 random numbers ? Should i use another three variables or there is a better way out?

Comment: `Math.random()` returns 0(inclusive)-1(exclusive), so in order to have a random number between 1-10 , it should be `var rand1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10)+1);`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use three other variables using the same random number generation function that you already have. Just make sure that these variables do not get the same value as the one which is correct i.e. `rand1`.

In other words before assigning the random number to each of the other variables check if they are equal to `rand1`. If the generated value is the same call the function again and only assign it if it is not equal.